# SSD Info showing incorrectly

Tags: ssd

When I check my SSD health using CrystalDiskInfo, it shows the info in the picture.

[image: The Disk Information]

Which is shown about 750PB of read, and 580PB of write. Which I think must be an error.
Is there anyway to fix the problem?

Edit:

From the smart info from the Micron Storage Executive Software, picture below

[image: SMART INFO from Micron]

It doesn't show any info related to Reads and Writes amount. But seems like the SSD lifetime is ending soon.

Thank you

Comment: Is there an app from the SSD manufacturer?  My SSD here (Samsung) show approximately 32TB written after 4 years of heavy use.

Comment: There is nothing to fix though? SMART does not define how RAW values work.

Comment: I try to use the Micron Software, information in post edit.

Comment: Try converting LBA to TB written with this:  https://www.virten.net/2016/12/ssd-total-bytes-written-calculator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has come up before - CrystalDiskInfo is wrong about the size of the
read/write data unit, so is multiplying their count by the wrong number.
Fortunately, calculating the correct number is easy.

The manual of your disk,
[1100 2.5-Inch and M.2 SATA NAND Flash SSD](https://www.edgeelectronics.com/product_images/pdf/micron_1100_ssd.pdf),
page 12, reports that Logical Block Size (LBA) is 512 bytes.

CrystalDiskInfo reports "Total LBA Read" as 5EC623963 hex or
25,440,696,675 decimal (which is very near to that given by the
Micron Storage Executive Software).

This gives as total 12131 GB of read bytes, or about 11.8 TB.

This number is large, but nowhere near the whopping 795,021,808 GB that are
reported by CrystalDiskInfo.
It's up to you to say whether the calculated number of 11.8 TB sounds logical.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gives me a relieve.